# PHP Check if number is smaller than array element values

Tags: php, arrays

This seems really simple but I can't figure out the cleanest way to do it...

Basically I have a sorted Array with numbers like this:

```
$array1 = [3, 7, 12, 63, 120, 512, 961];
```

What I need to do is check each element of the array against a number which can be like this:

```
$number = 320;
```

And I need to get the element which is next to the number in this example it would be 120 because `120 < $number < 512`.

Well, my way approach which kinda works is pretty messy I think:

```
foreach ($i = 0; $i < count($array1); $i++) {
    if ($array[$i] < $number) {
        // echo "do nothing, elements are smaller than number
    } else {
        if ($flag == true) {
            // echo "elements are not smaller anymore and flag is set"
            $getValue = $array[$i-1]; // last element which was smaller
            $flag == false;
        }
    }
}
```

Another problem is, I need to cover the cases if `$number` is smaller than the smallest element of the array or if its larger than the largest element of the array. For that case I create another Variable `$t` and check it with the length of the array in each iteration

```
$t = 0;
$len = count($array1);

// if element bigger than number and first iteration
if ($array[$i] > $number && $t == 0) {

}
$t += 1;
```

I left the foreach loop out here but as you can probably see it gets really long and its certainly not clean. How can it be done better?

Comment: you're using an assignment operator `&& $t = 0)` rather than a comparison `&& $t == 0)` or `&& $t === 0)`

Answer (score 0):

As it is an sorted array you are working with then i recommend you to implement binary search algorithm which has O(log(n)) in time complexity .

```
 int binary_search(int A[], int key, int imin, int imax)
 {
  // continue searching while [imin,imax] is not empty
  while (imin <= imax)
    {
      // calculate the midpoint for roughly equal partition
      int imid = midpoint(imin, imax);
      if(A[imid] == key)
        // key found at index imid
        return imid; 
      // determine which subarray to search
      else if (A[imid] < key)
        // change min index to search upper subarray
        imin = imid + 1;
      else         
        // change max index to search lower subarray
        imax = imid - 1;
    }
  // key was not found
  return KEY_NOT_FOUND;
}
```

source: wikipedia.org

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = [3, 7, 12, 63, 120, 512, 961];
$min = 0;
$max = count($array)-1;
$no = 320;
while ($min < $max)
{
  $mid = (int)(($min+$max)/2);
  if ($array[$mid] == $no) {
    print $array[$mid-1]."<".$no."<".$array[$mid+1];
    return;
  }
  else if($array[$mid] < $no) {
    $min = $mid+1;
  } else {
    $max = $mid-1;
  }
  if($min == $max ) {
    if($array[$min] > $no) {
        print $array[$min-1]."<".$no."<".$array[$min];
        return;
    } else {
        print $array[$min]."<".$no."<".$array[$min+1];
        return;
    }
  }
}
```